# Problem with rails ckeditor plugin and basic authentication

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, image-uploading

Using the [rails-ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor/wiki) and I'm getting a 401 exception anytime I try to upload an image using the "Browse Server" and then "Upload" buttons.  I'm securing my site right now using simple basic authentication as such

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate

  def logged_in?
    # cookies[:auth].present?
  end

  def authenticate
    # unless logged_in?
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |login, password|
        if(login == "user1" && password == "password")
          cookies.permanent.signed[:auth] = login
        end
      end
    # end
  end

  def current_church
    @current_church ||= Church.first
  end

end
```

If I disable basic authentication everything works fine.  Is there a remedy for this?

Thanks -wg

Comment: Looks like it is using SWFUpload so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with using SWFUpload (flash) to send up cookies.

This link got me looking in the right direction:
http://ruby-on-rails-development.co.uk/2011/05/23/securing-ckeditor-file-management

The solution is to follow the directiosn from that article with the following additions:

1. In the flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb file add

   env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [ 'auth', params['auth'] ].join('=').freeze
2. In the base_helper.rb file (under /app/helpers/ckeditor) add the following:

   options['auth'] = Rack::Utils.escape(cookies[:auth])

The latest source for this gem handles session based tokens and the authenticity token already.  This simple hack is only needed if your going with a cookie based approach to managing your authentication ticket.